# What is causing my dice game to show an unrealistic amount of perfect rolls

Tags: java, random

I am trying to create a die rolling program. The goal is to roll a die until the chosen value comes up a certain number of consecutive times (I used the programmer defined name "rollLength" for this). I am trying to display how many total rolls it took until the die value comes up consecutively. The problem is when I run the program it shows that the rollLength came up perfectly with no wasted rolls which I know is unrealistic. My question is if you can suggest what is wrong with my code. I am not sure if I am doing nested loops wrong.
Here is my code.

```
package lab03_schultz;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lab03_Schultz {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // WRITE main's CODE HERE 
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       Random randomNumber = new Random();

       //declare variables
       int value, nSides, rollLength, roll;
       int turns=0, n=0, count=0, totalThrows=0; 

       //ask for input
       System.out.println("Please enter the number of sides (2, 4, or 6): ");
       nSides = keyboard.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Enter the value sought. Must be in the range [1," + nSides + "]: ");
       value = keyboard.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Enter the length of the run.\n" + "Remember, the bigger it is the longer it will take to find it");
       rollLength = keyboard.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Enter number of times to run the experiment:"); 
       turns = keyboard.nextInt();


      while(n!=value) {
          roll = randomNumber.nextInt(nSides)+1;
          n++;
      }
      while(count!=rollLength){  //countinue till count = rollLength
        if(n==value){
            count++;     //count how many times n == value, this is to represent consective rolls for the value
        } else if (n!=value) {  //if n is not the value counter starts over at zero
                count=0;
        }
        if (n!=value) {//This will count how many times the die didn't come up with the value
            totalThrows++; 
        } 
      }
      System.out.println("totalThrows: " + totalThrows); //finding what totalThrows is

        //adds rolls (without watched value) and (when it showed watch value) together
      System.out.println("Your total throws are: " + (totalThrows+rollLength)); 

   }
}
```

Comment: For starters, I guess, that first loop does nothing as far as I can tell, besides increasing N linearly till it == value.

Also, this smacks of homework.  Just saying'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with just a single loop

```
int rollsInARow = 0; // store how many times we roll the value
int totalThrows = 0;

while(rollsInARow != rollLength) {
    int roll = randomNumber.nextInt(nSides)+1;
    if(roll == value) {
        rollsInARow++; // Count consecutive rolls that are the wanted value
    } else {
        rollsInARow = 0; // Reset if we get a roll other than value 
    }
    totalThrows++; // +1 after each roll
}
```

We loop until we have the wanted rollLength. Each loop generates a random number and compares it to value. If they are equal, increment the counter. If different, reset the counter. At the end of each loop, keep track of total rolls.

Also a tip. When using an `if` statement to check a true/false value (`n == value`), you can simply use an else statement to catch the `n != value` because there are only two cases.

```
    if(n == value) {
        count++;
    } else { // The same functionality as else if(n != value)
        count = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first while loop will run until n is equal to the value. It will not move past that block of code until **n** is equal to **value**.